# How to install SSIS/SSDT custom task on SERVER

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have created a SSIS Custom Task and installed it on my development machine, which included using gacutil and copying the dll file to appropriate folders.  Now packages using this Custom Task need to be run on multiple different MS SQL Servers (2014).  While I can find plenty of documentation to install and run locally, I have found nothing on how to install the finished product on the server.

One of the problems I've come across is that on the server only SQL Server is installed. No Visual Studio on the server, so gacutil isn't there.

Can someone tell me where I need to put the dll file and what needs to be done so that when these packages are run the task doesn't error because it isn't there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a whole bunch of research, I have found that the dll file(s) need to be placed into [SQLSERVERINSTALLDIRECTORY] this is generally C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server[version]\DTS\Tasks\ folder for x86 and C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server[version]\DTS\Tasks\
Note Tasks folder is for tasks; Connections, PibelineComponents go into their respective directories.

The information about what directories to put it into was found in a tutorial about creating an installer. It can be found at: https://blog.tallan.com/2017/02/02/creating-an-effortless-custom-ssis-object-installer-using-wix/

The [version] needs to be replaced by the appropriate version.  For me using SSIS 2014 it was 120.  The versions are: 2017 = 140; 2016 = 130; 2014 = 120; 2012 = 110; 2008 = 100.  Note that 2008 R2 and below have some different requirements.
The information about versions was found at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321185/how-to-determine-the-version-edition-and-update-level-of-sql-server-an

The dll file also needs to be installed into the GAC (Global Assembly Cache). To do this, generally a tool like gacutil needs to be installed on the server.  This can also be done through powershell, or by using an installer.

I was able to install on the server by copying into the appropriate directories and using powershell to put it into the GAC.  To install into the GAC using powershell, the command was:
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
$publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish
$publish.GACInstall("C:\path\to\dll.dll")

This information was found at https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/16/using-powershell-to-install-a-dll-into-the-gac/

While I used a manual method to install on the first server that needed the component, I am working on making a working installer for it.  I believe that would probably be the better way as it can be tracked and uninstalled.  Plus it would make things easier if you have to deal with multiple servers.